# I have problems regarding the readings of my qtr-8a sensor in a line follower

Tags: mobile-robot

I have several theories, the problem is quite simple, I have a program to auto-calibrate it on the line, when reading the line where it calibrates it works perfectly, the problem is when it starts to move away from the area where it was calibrated or change direction for example, from the straight line there is a small curve towards another direction, the reading begins to fail and it goes out of line, I thought at first that it was the distance from the sensor to the floor, it did not work, another is that it calibrated with the connected computer to the arduino and at the moment of connecting the batteries the problem persisted, I tried to add a frame for the possible problem of ambient light, it didn't work either, any possible solution?